# How to combine bind values in to a new variable in Angular2/4

Tags: angular, angular-template

Hi I have the following Angular 4 template code code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <td>
        <a [routerLink]="['/test/test1', id1, id2]">
            {{row.summary[0].width}}
            {{row.summary[0].length}}
            {{row.summary[0].vol}}
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now I want to change the url path to the following:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/test/test1', item.id1, newID]">
```

the new ID(id2) must be the combined value of

```
id2 = {{row.summary[0].width}}
{{row.summary[0].length}}
{{row.summary[0].vol}}
```

How can I do that in Angular?

Comment: What is the final url, can you give an example.  /test/test1?newID=****

Comment: nope. It should be `/test/test1/newID`

Comment: does it like /test/test1/width/length/vol ?

Comment: Hi i have editted the question

Comment: What is wrong with `[routerLink]="['/test/test1', item.id1, row.summary[0].width + row.summary[0].length + row.summary[0].vol]"`? Assuming `item` is appropriate defined somewhere.

Comment: Oh it worked. How stupid I am. Thanks torazoburo

Answer (score 2):

Just create property in your component:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() { }

  getNewId(sum): string {
    return `${sum.width}${sum.length}${sum.vol}`;
  }
}
```

And use in template:

```
<td>
  <a [routerLink]="['/test/test1', getNewId(row.summary[0])]">
    {{row.summary[0].width}}
    {{row.summary[0].length}}
    {{row.summary[0].vol}}
  </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Hi, actually the value i get is from *ngFor. I cant process the value in my component

Comment: Actually you can, just create component method which accepts row summary and returns `newId`